# If I use react-drag-drop's fileUploader component, gives error while reuploading the same file. but it uploads another file properly

Tags: reactjs

In my Reactjs project, I used react-drag-drop fileUploader component to upload the file. Then I clear/delete the uploaded file. If I again upload the same file, it will not upload. But it upload another file properly.
while I use react-drag-drop fileUploader component , I get a event triggered whenever I drag drop a same file on ntime through onDrop attribute & but I cant get any event triggered on Select function (In chrome & edge). It works properly in firefox.
sample code:

```
  import React, { useState } from "react";
  import { FileUploader } from "react-drag-drop-files";

  const fileTypes = ["JPG", "PNG", "GIF"];

  function DragDrop() {
    const [file, setFile] = useState(null);
    const handleSelect = (file) => {
    setFile(file);
  };
  const handleDrop = () => {
    setFile(null);
  };
  const handleChange = (file) => {
    setFile(file);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <FileUploader
        onChange={handleChange}
        onSelect={handleSelect}
        name="file"
        types={fileTypes}
        fileOrFiles={file}
      />
      <br />
      <button onClick={handleDrop}>Delete</button>
    </>
  );
}

export default DragDrop;
```

Comment: Can you add this into a codesandbox  and share the url where we can reproduce this issue, also worth checking this example where I don't see any error for same file upload again https://sghbp.csb.app/

Comment: Hi @arung86 , here I upload the file ,then  delete the file using delete button .Then I try to reupload the same file . It will not upload.